# Fiat 500e 2017 baby carseat installation

Tags: fiat, seat-belt, seat-cars, child-seat

I was wondering if anyone tried to put baby carseat in the Fiat 500 car, and how it works? Is it required to have a base or the seatbelt is enough?? [image]

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! It looks as though it is designed to be used with the base [as seen in the instruction manual](https://uk.joiebaby.com/wp-content/uploads/sites/19/2019/05/p-im0478a_1-i-snug_im_20190321.pdf). I think it can be used either way, but the prefered method is with the base.

Answer (score 0):

Acording to fiat official website, and the [virtual 3d configurator](https://www.fiat.com/500-electric-virtual-3d-experience) fiat 500e equipment includes [Isofix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isofix) system on back seats. You need to check if the Joie car seat allows isofix connections.